# Dynamic typing of subclasses using generics in Python

Tags: python, generics, inheritance, subclass, python-typing

Let's say i have to following classes.

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        pass

class B(A):
    pass
```

And I have some kind of function that constructs an object based on it's type as well as calls a function.

```
def create(cls: Type[A]) -> A:
    cls.foo()
    return cls()
```

Now I can make the following calls to that function. And because `B` inherits from `A` it's all good.

```
instance_a: A = create(A)
instance_b: B = create(B)
```

Except the with the latter, type-checking will start complaining because `create` according to the annotations returns an instance of `A`.

This could be solved with `TypeVar` as follows.

```
from typing import Type, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')
def create(cls: Type[T]) -> T:
   cls.foo() 
   return cls()
```

Except now the typing checking doesn't do it's original job of guarantying that `cls` has a method called `foo`. Is there a way to specify a generic to be of a certain type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[You can supply a bound](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-variables-with-an-upper-bound):

```py
T = TypeVar('T', bound=A)
```